# VB.NET: What is static T (C#) in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-to-vb.net

Consider:

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)

 T returnValue = default(T);
```

I want to implement something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/skillet/archive/2008/06/18/idatareader-extension-methods.aspx) to check DBNull. I can follow the code fine, but I don't quite understand what static T is in VB.NET. Can someone please explain it a bit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent of `static` in VB in `Shared`. Shared methods are usually put in Helper classes, because they do not require an instance of the class to run.

The type T indicates that this is a generic method (this is a new feature in VB 9 and C# 3). A generic method effectively takes a type as an argument or returns a generic type.

Extension methods are also new in VB 9/C# 3. These allow you to extend an existing type by adding methods. All you need is a Shared method which is available in the same namespace as your code, and in VB the code has to be in a module, not a normal class.

A module is a class that can't be instantiated and (therefore) only has shared methods. It is declared with the Module keyword in place of the class keyword. Here is your code in VB.

(Also for those that know what's going on "under the covers" strangely setting a value type to `Nothing` does compile in VB and is the supported way to get the default value of a value type).

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
<Extension()> _
Public Shared Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ByVal reader As IDataReader, ByVal columnName As String) As T
Dim returnValue As T = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Very close, however you forgot to show the extension method syntax.

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding the forgotten attribute in the code snippet Joel.

Comment: Also, I believe Shared is invalid here as extension methods must be inside Modules.

Comment: yes, @ScottE, you are correct. Attempting to add 'Shared' to a method in a `Module` produces this error: "Methods in a Module cannot be declared 'Shared'." But of course, they really are static methods, so C# requires extension methods to be declared as `static`.

Comment: (Since i tested that 'Shared' was invalid in VB.NET, and I was now 100% certain that it was invalid [in VS 2010], i took the liberty to edit this answer to remove `Shared` from the function declaration.)

Answer (score 1):

He's creating an extension method.  In C#, that's done by creating a static method (Shared in Visual Basic).

The mechanism for creating extension methods in Visual Basic appears to be much different than how you do it in C#.  You'll probably want to read the MSDN entry about extension methods, here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is what the method would look like in VB:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices 

<Extension()> _
Public Shared Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ByVal reader As IDataReader, ByVal columnName As String) as T
    Dim returnvalue As T = Nothing
End Function
```

I'm not sure how to do default(T) in VB so I left it out.

Comment: Thanks, I moved to C# a while ago and have forgotten everything about VB.  I have fixed it up.

Comment: VS gives this error when you use `Shared` on methods in a `Module`: Methods in a Module cannot be declared 'Shared'. (I tested and verified this in VS 2010.) I took the liberty to remove `Shared` from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is not "static T", but two separate parts.

- public denotes the method as publicly visible.
- static denotes the method as static. This means it runs for the class, not for an instance.
- T - is the return type.

More information on [static function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Static functions in VB.NET are know as shared functions.

More information on [shared functions](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1047/new-objectoriented-capabilities-in-vbnet/5/).

Comment: I believe the asker wants to know the VB.Net equivalent to static T.

Comment: Oh that was confusing as hell.

Comment: Yeah, he could have definitely done a better job at wording his question.

Comment: Yeah, there are atleast 3 questions being asked at once ;-)

Comment: Hi, Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

C#'s static keyword is the same as VB's Shared keyword.

Comment: not always. extension methods are a different animal altogether. the *concepts* are one and the same, yes. but the *syntax* on how extension methods are declared differs and thus in C#, we need the `static` keyword with the first parameter declared as `this`. But both of these differ in VB.NET. Both require the `extension` attribute tho. the question is actually lacking this extension method, but the `this` keyword clues us in that it is indeed a C# extension method (without the required `extension` attribute being supplied).

Comment: so the C# `static` *concept* and the VB `shared` *concept* are one and the same. but the keywords are not the same since the *syntax* differs considerably when declaring extension methods. :P oh, how such a better design would have caused a lot less confusion if there was more conformity between the two. but they are different programming languages, and truthfully, there's no reason why 2 different programming languages need any similarity at all. but it would have been very helpful. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

T in your example is the type-parameter in your generic method.

In VB:

```
Public Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ByVal reader as IDataReader, ByVal columnName as string) as T
```

Means that when you call the method, you supply a type-parameter (telling what type T will be for the call to the method)

Not sure about the VB syntax for creating an extension method, though. (This is what the "this" keyword on your first parameter denotes.)

Comment: close, but you forgot "Public Function", and that the original is an extension method.