# Class (of T) - What is T?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I understand the basics of generics i.e. it is validation and removed by the compiler.  I see plenty of code like this:

```
Public Class Person(Of T)

End Class
```

I do not fully understand what T is.  I would expect something like Of Person or Of Order as T does not exist in my problem domain.

I believe what this is saying is that all references to T in the class must be the class instance, but I am not sure.

I have spent some time Googling this and I have even reread the Generics section of an Object Oriented text book I own.  I have not yet found an answer.

Comment: I think it stands for Type...it means you will define it later such as `List(of Person)`

Answer (score 1):

It is a parameter; although `T` is the most commonly used name, other names would be possible.  If one considers a method definition:

```
Sub Foo(Bar As Integer)
```

the `T` in a type definition plays much the same role as the `Bar` in a method definition.  The most notable thing about generic type parameters is unlike parameter definitions which in the sane (`Option Strict Off`) dialect of VB must always specify a type [the `As Integer`], generic type parameters can specify a constraint type `Class Foo(Of T As Control)` but are not required to do so.  Further, even when a constraint type is specified, `T` is not an *instance* of `Control`, but rather a type which is required to *derive* from `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

T stands for Type. (in C++ it's template, though)

It means that the method is static, or generic.

The T itself indicates that the method is generic.

If you understand generics, it should make sense to you that it's kind of a placeholder. 
(if i understand correctly)

This should explain why

```
Public Class Person(Of T)

End Class
```

is like Public Class (of ________ (type) ______)

[VB.net: What is static T (C#) in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467642/vb-net-what-is-static-t-c-in-vb-net)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is just a placeholder to signify that the Type will be defined at runtime:

```
Public Class Elements(Of T)
    Private mList as List(of T)

...
End Class

...

Friend El as New Elements(of String)
```

My code creates an El object and passes the T (String) to the Class which I can use to define the inner workings.  It is a way to use typed objects as opposed to inheriting numerous classes of each likely datatype, or just declaring such things as Object.

Sometimes you'll see 2 of them:

```
Foo(Of T, Of TT)
```

It just means there are 2 Types to be defined later.  There is nothing special about `T` - it is just convention, `Of` is the keyword.